# resuming transfer of files over ssh from remote linux to local windows

Tags: sftp

I was wondering what are the best ways on local Windows for resuming transfer of files over ssh from remote linux?

I tried SSHSecureShellClient-3.2.9, but I cannot find it works for resuming.

I tried Putty's psftp. It also seems not having the resuming ability.

************** update ****************

When using WinSCP to transfer many files, if I cancel the transfer in the halfway, will the files not transferred yet and not fully transferred be saved so that I can resume their transfer next time when I get a faster connection? I am worried if I have to manually compare the source and destination files to figure out what files are already transferred and what are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net) has [transfer resume](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume) capability. It's a graphical client rather than command-line but, as graphical clients go, it's very nice.

Comment: Thanks Evan! When using WinSCP to transfer many files, if I cancel the transfer in the halfway, will the files not transferred yet and not fully transferred be saved so that I can resume their transfer next time when I get a faster connection? I am worried if I have to manually compare the source and destination files to figure out what files are already transferred and what are not.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync can also resume a file upload - even if it wasn't the original application to start the upload. Unfortunately, Windows doesn't have rsync built in. However, there is a version available called cwRsync.

Comment: deltacopy is another rsync implementation for windows. It's a bit simpler to install than cwRsync